# Centralisers in Thompson's group $V_n$

Tags: gr.group-theory

In the article *[Centralizers in R. Thompson group $V_n$](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=1661-7207&vol=7&iss=4&rank=2)*, the following question is asked:

> **Question:** Is the centraliser of an element of $V_n$ always finitely presented?

I am wondering: is this question still open? I have a plausible argument in mind, but I would like to be sure that the answer is not already somewhere in the literature.

Comment: You can ask Collin Bleak, he certainly knows the answer to your question. Alternatively use google scholar to find all texts on the internet referring to this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question. In *[Centralizers in R. Thompson group $V_n$](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=1661-7207&vol=7&iss=4&rank=2)*, it is proved that the centraliser of an element of $V_n$ decomposes as 
$$ \left( \prod\limits_{i=1}^s K_{m_i} \rtimes G_{n,r_i} \right) \times \left( \prod\limits_{j=1}^t (( A_j \rtimes \mathbb{Z} ) \wr P_{j}) \right)$$
where

- $A_1, \ldots, A_t, P_{1}, \ldots, P_t$ are finite groups;
- $K_{m_i} = \mathrm{Maps}(\mathfrak{C}_n, \mathbb{Z}_{m_i})^{r_i}$ where $\mathrm{Maps}(\mathfrak{C}_n,\mathbb{Z}_{m_i})$ is the group of continuous maps from the Cantor set $\mathfrak{C}_n$ to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{m_i}$ (endowed with the discrete topology) under pointwise multiplication;
- $G_{n,r_i}$ is the Higman-Thompson group.

The right factor is virtually $\mathbb{Z}^t$, so no problem here. And it follows from Theorem 4.9 in *[Cohomological finiteness conditions and centralisers in generalisations
of Thompson's group $V$](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/form.ahead-of-print/forum-2014-0176/forum-2014-0176.xml)* that the left factor is of type $F_\infty$ (i.e., it admits a classifying space containing finitely many cells in each dimension).

It follows that centralisers in $V_n$ are not only finitely presented, they are of type $F_\infty$.

Comment: It seems that you're using two different notations in the same post for $V_n$ (which is among the $G_{n,m}$). I guess that all you say applies for centralizers in arbitrary Higman-Thompson groups (the restriction to $V_n$ is not natural).

Comment: The decomposition of centralisers is stated and proved only for $V_n$. It seems reasonable to think that the argument also applies to Higman-Thompson groups, but I prefer to refer to a statement which is actually proved.

Comment: OK I see, it would require checking whether any specific thing is used ($V_n$ is just one particular choice among the $n-1$ Higman-Thompson groups $V_{n,m}$ for $m\in\mathbf{Z}/(n-1)\mathbf{Z}$).